# Xamarin MvvmCross Command en un boton

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

Hola amigos estoy aprendiendo a usar **MvvmCross** con **Xamarin** y quiero ejecutar un comando que me imprima los datos de un textview a un label cuando le click a un boton, esto lo que tengo hasta ahora.
Este es mi ViewModel de Cross

```
    public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
          private string _description;

    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            _description = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }



    public MvxCommand MyCommand { get; private set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new MvxCommand(SetValueCommand);
    }

    private void SetValueCommand()
    {
        // Description = ??? ; aqui quiero tomar el valor del EditText y mandarlo al textview
    }
}
```

este mi axml para android

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mytextview"
    android:text=""
    />

<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    app:MvxBind="Text Description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
    android:text="Set Data"
    app:MvxBind="Click SetValueCommand"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Conozco como usarlo para Xamarin.Forms. te ayuda?

Comment: @RamiroBarone hola ramiro, pues claro porque no si me es de ayuda te lo hago saber

Comment: Pero deberias manejar la vista con Forms y no un proyecto de android.